# How to install React native app to wireless router

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have question regarding installing React Native application to **WIRELESS LAN CONTROLLER** this system like captive portal.

Question:

1. How can i install my application to this router?
2. Is this possible to install my application to that router?

Thank you.

[image: Wireless Router]

Comment: what is this for? is it a mobile application you want to connect with router?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't.
2. No, its impossible

maybe you you meant is react for building website, react native is for building multiplatform apps (e.g Ios and Android).